# Are SSH keys and PGP keys the same thing?

Tags: public-key-infrastructure, key-management, pgp, rsa

I have a 3072 bit RSA key that I generated for use with SSH. Can this key-pair be used with PGP/GPG, or do I need to generate a new pair of keys separately for use in email encryption?

Are the two interchangeable, or is there a difference between the two?

Comment: Even if they were, it's generally a bad idea to re-use the same key across multiple contexts.

Comment: Both PGP and SSH support RSA public/private key pairs, so presumably it is possible.

Comment: @StephenTouset would you elaborate why this is not a good idea in this case?

Comment: See also [this answer](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/1806/why-should-one-not-use-the-same-asymmetric-key-for-encryption-as-they-do-for-sig) for why not to use the same key for signing and encryption. The reasoning about key management extends to SSH authentication too.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Yes, the same RSA key pair can be used for both (Open)SSL and OpenPGP/GnuPG.

The [monkeysphere project](http://web.monkeysphere.info/) contains a tool to convert RSA keys in PEM format to the one defined by OpenPGP, [`pem2openpgp`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/maverick/man1/pem2openpgp.1.html). For converting the SSH key pair into the PEM format, there already is a comprehensive answer in [Converting keys between openssl and openssh](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/32768/converting-keys-between-openssl-and-openssh).