# Can't sign commit with yubikey, GPG missing something

Tags: digital-signature, gnupg, yubikey, code-signing, git

I don't know much about how yubikeys work, but I'm trying to sign a commit with one of them and I don't even know how to debug the problem. I got:

```
gpg --list-keys
/home/lz/.gnupg/pubring.kbx
---------------------------
pub   ed25519 2018-11-30 [SC]
      123456...ABCDEF
uid           [ unknown] proton@srp.modulus
sub   cv25519 2018-11-30 [E]
```

and

```
git commit -m "hdle" -S 
error: gpg failed to sign the data
fatal: failed to write commit object
```

and

```
gpg --status-fd=2 -bsau 'MyName <myname@protonmail.com>'
gpg: skipped "MyName <myname@protonmail.com>": No secret key
[GNUPG:] INV_SGNR 9 MyName <myname@protonmail.com>
[GNUPG:] FAILURE sign 17
gpg: signing failed: No secret key
```

**PS: SSH login works with yubikey**

**UPDATE:**

```
echo "test" | gpg --clearsign
gpg: no default secret key: No secret key
gpg: [stdin]: clear-sign failed: No secret key
```

Comment: I find it easier to troubleshoot by first trying to sign a generic message (rather than a commit) first, using `echo "test" | gpg --clearsign`.

Comment: @keithRozario added an update

Comment: What do you get with "gpg --list-secret-keys"?

Comment: @thenickdude empty response

Comment: @thenickdude how can I do SSH if I have no secret keys?

Comment: SSH login does not use PGP keys but SSH keys. Despite the same RSA keys [could be used for both](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/66482/70406), the format is different and a conversion would be required.

Comment: This might be helpful for using Yubikey with both SSH & PGP: https://github.com/drduh/YubiKey-Guide

Comment: @EsaJokinen I followed this guide enitrely, and after many months using the yubikey, I now get a problem on another computer in which it was not setted up initially