# ed25519-sk vs. gpg-agent on Yubikey

Tags: public-key-infrastructure, ssh, gnupg, yubikey

According to my understanding of [this document](https://github.com/vorburger/vorburger.ch-Notes/blob/develop/security/ed25519-sk.md), Yubikey is capable of running `ed25519-sk` and `gpg-agent`.

Which one is more secure? Obviously, `ed25519-sk` wouldn't work, if the SSH server is old, but other than that, is there any downside of using `ed25519-sk` vs. `gpg-agent`?

Comment: This seems like a similar question to this one: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/264365/what-are-the-security-implications-of-using-gpg-instead-of-ssh-keys-for-authenti/264851#264851

Answer (score 1):

As of 2022, you should prefer Ed25519 wherever possible.

The only scenarios where other signature algorithms might be preferred over Ed25519 are:

- You are legally or contractually prohibited from using Ed25519, e.g. for regulatory reasons (like FIPS).
- The systems you need to interact with do not support Ed25519.

If you'd like a more in-depth evaluation of the options, I recommend Soatok's [guide to digital signature algorithms (2020)](https://soatok.blog/2020/04/26/a-furrys-guide-to-digital-signature-algorithms/) and [guidance for elliptic curve signature algorithms (2022)](https://soatok.blog/2022/05/19/guidance-for-choosing-an-elliptic-curve-signature-algorithm-in-2022/).

Comment: A downvote is only useful if it comes with an explanatory comment.